# Get path of directoryinfo object

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

Writing some code in C#, I was wondering if there was a way to get the correct path of a directoryinfo object?

Currently I have, for example, a directory such as:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathToDirectory);
```

The issue is that if I want to get the path of that specific `dirInfo` object, it always returns the debug path (bin folder). If the original dirInfo object is referencing a directory in the `D:\testDirectory` path, then I want a way to get that path again somewhere else in the code instead of getting `\bin\debug\testDirectory`

Is there any way to do this?

Currently I am trying to get the path of dirInfo using `Path`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Path: " + Path.GetFullPath(dirInfo.ToString()));
```

Comment: What is pathToDirectory? Is it D:\testDirectory or the debug path?

Comment: how are you getting the path for `dirInfo` ?

Comment: Can you please show code that you use to get "path of `DirectoryInfo`"? And for sample code try to use constant values where possible (i.e. what is value of  `pathToDirectory` when your code does not work)

Comment: @JustinPihony pathToDirectory is the string @"D:\testDirectory"

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Edited my code to show how I am trying to get the path.

Comment: so what are you getting if you try to print the path on console?

Comment: so what is the exact problem , are you not able to get the proper path which was assigned to DirectoryInfo?

Comment: You are either not showing your code OR don't know what is passed to it: `Path.GetFullPath(new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\testDirectory ").ToString())` returns "D:\testDirectory" as expected. Please double check your sample.

Comment: This isn't as silly as it might sound to some, I've had a similar problem: If you create a folder using `Directory.CreateDirectory("some\\relative\\pathtest")` it returns a `DirectoryInfo` instance, _but_ if you call `.ToString()` on it then it will _only_ return the same as the Name property, in this case: `"pathtest"` - which is really weird, you would expect CreateDirectory to pass on the original string - but it doesn't!

Comment: _...cont:_ Actually looking at the latest reference source it looks like they have fixed this? When I wonder - .net4.0 or 4.5? (Hasty look at source: appears it returns the full path now - so still not what you passed, but a lot better at least.)

Answer (score 50):

Try this.

```
string pathToDirctory = "D:\\testDirectory";
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(pathToDirctory);
string path = dirInfo.FullName;
Console.WriteLine(path);
```

Comment: @user1806716 - note that this code behaves exactly the same as code that you claim to have - [DirectoryInfoToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) "Returns the original path that was passed by the user."

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: i think OP is sending the "testDirectory" relative path hence it is getting added to the current path(dubug folder).

Comment: @user1806716 6 minutes... :)

Answer (score 3):

A `DirectoryInfo` represents a particular directory. When you create it, what directory it represents is dependent on the path you give it. If you give it an *absolute* path like `c:\foo\bar\baz\bat`, that's the directory you get. If, on the other hand, you give it a *relative* path, like `foo\bar\baz\bat`, the path is relative to the process' *current working directory*. By default, that is inherited from the process that spawned the current process. Visual Studio starts a debug session and sets the CWD of the process being debugged to its `bin` directory. So if you create a `DirectoryInfo` and give it a path like `testDirectory`, you will get a `DirectoryInfo` about `[project-root]\bin\Debug\testDirectory`.

If you want an absolute path, you'll have to specify that absolute path. There aren't any shortcuts.

Comment: so here OP must be giving the Relative path to the DirectoryInfo instead of absolute path that is why he is getting path as=> projectfolder/bin/debug/DitestDirectory right?